# Is `if($_POST)` a reliable means of checking if a script has been posted?

Tags: php, postdata

As per the title: is `if($_POST)` reliable?

Is it reliably `true` even if no data was posted but the HTTP POST method was used?

Is `if('post' === strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']))` a more reliable method, or is it overkill?

Comment: May I ask, what is the purpose of this test? Anyway, second method is not overkill, I wouldn't rely on PHP conversions, if I were you :)

Comment: I usually do `if (isset($_POST['nameofsubmitbutton']))`

Comment: As Evert says, this won't detect a POST method with no posted variables - but I find it hard to imagine why, if such a situation should arise, it is still necessary to differentiate between methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.. because:

array() == false

So if no data is posted, the condition will turn out false. So check against the REQUEST_METHOD. Note that it would have taken you less time to test this, than for me to type this out.

Comment: it depends whether you want to determine whether a post request was made, or whether you want to check whether some data was actually submitted

Comment: I'd say that generally speaking it's the request method you actually care about. The fact that there's no data can be handled afterward.